# submitting looping forms with jquery/ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have forms being created in a foreach loop with php.

Each form has a lpformnum that increases

```
<form lpformnum="1"><button class="update" /></form>
<form lpformnum="2"><button class="update" /></form>
<form lpformnum="3"><button class="update" /></form>
etc.
```

I am using jquery/ajax to prevent the default action of the forms so I can submit the forms via ajax.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){        
        $('.alert').on('click', 'button[class=update]', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
            var checkValues = $("#update").val();
            var checkCred = $("#ucredits").val();
            var checkPost = $("textarea").text();
            var checkType = $("i").text();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "update_social_cred.php",
                data: { id: checkValues, credits: checkCred, text: checkPost, type: checkType  },
                success:function(result) {
                 alert (checkCred);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is, every button submits the first form drawn on the page. How would I do this so each button is set to each form keeping in mind there are an unknown number of forms being drawn?

Comment: What is `#update`? `#ucredits`?

Comment: He didn't  paste the full code, probably.

Comment: Listen for `submit` event, not `click`. Also assign `type="submit"` attribute to your buttons

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you should clarify what data you want to submit with `find()` method.

```
$('.alert').on('click', 'button[class=update]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // find parent form of a button
    var form = $(this).closest( "form" );

    // I suppose these are unique fields.
    var checkValues = $("#update").val();
    var checkCred = $("#ucredits").val();
    var checkPost = $("textarea").text();
    // if they are not you should use classes instead:
    // something like:
    // var checkCred = form.find(".ucredits").val();

    // find values in a `form` with `find` method
    var checkType = form.find("i").text();

    // pass your data to ajax.
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the variables relate to this problem in any way, as all the variables are working perfectly, in fact, it will submit the first form perfectly, just none of the others.

Comment: So what is the difference in forms?

Comment: I completely get what you were saying! I took me a while staring at the code. Just switch everything to find the nearest form to the button, and use find to find the classes names closest to that given form when submitting. Genius!